# Want to remove index.php with the help of .htaccess file

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, url

I want to remove `index.php` from my URL and updated my `.htaccess` file with following code.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On 
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

but it didn't work for me. To check whether the `.htaccess` file is working, I removed all codes from file however my project is still working fine with `index.php`. That means my project is working without `.htaccess` file? then how can I remove `index.php` with the help of `.htaccess` file?

I am using linux server.

Comment: Laravel includes a public/.htaccess file that is used to provide URLs without the index.php front controller in the path. Before serving Laravel with Apache, be sure to enable the  mod_rewrite module so the .htaccess file will be honored by the server. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/installation#web-server-configuration

Comment: Does your URL work without the `index.php` present in the URL? Is your application constructing URLs that contain `.index.php` or have this crept in and been indexed by accident?

Answer (score 2):

Some of my URLs were crawled by Google with "index.php". I used the code below to redirect "bad" URLs to correct once, without index.php.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Remove the index.php from url: hope it helps you.**

1) Rename the **server.php** file with **index.php**, which is in your project root directory.

2) And Copy the **.htaccess** file from **public** folder and paste it **root directory**.